# How Load DataGridView With BackgroundWorker

Tags: datagridview, backgroundworker

I Work on C# Project

in My Project I have 2 Windowns Form (Form A And Form B). and Form A is Parent of Form B.
Also I have a DataGridView In Form A And a Button On Form B.

When this Button Clicked (in form B) . the DataGridView in Form A Must be Reload. For this I Make a BackgroundWorker in Form B and Call LoadDataGridview Method From Form A.

But My Problem is:

Sometimes (Not always) When Button Clicked I Give a Problem (null object) and DataGridview Rows Disappears and 2 red line visible in Diameter.

My LoadDataGridview Method is this:

```
public void LoadDataGridview()
{

MyMethod.DGV.SaveDataGridViewMetaData(dgvPersons);


        objDataViewPersons = SqlServerDB.SqlMethod.GetContentOfTableWithDataView("Persons");

        objDataViewPersons.Table.Columns.Add("Department2", typeof(string));            

        if (objDataViewPersons.Table.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            btnEditPerson.Enabled = false;
            btnLastPerson.Enabled = false;
            btnShow.Enabled = false;
            btnPrint.Enabled = false;
        }

        foreach (DataRow drcurrent in objDataViewPersons.Table.Rows)
        {
            drcurrent["Department2"] = GlobalVar.CmbControl.GetNam(ComboBoxControl.ListName.Department, ComboBoxControl.ListInput.ID, drcurrent["Department"].ToString());
        }

        objBindingSource.DataSource = objDataViewPersons;

        MyMethod.DGV.RestoreDataGridViewMetaData(dgvPersons);
    }
```

How Reload DataGridView Quick And Without Error?

Answer (score 0):

I would look into creating User Controls.

User controls are a way of making a custom, reusable component. A user control can contain other controls but must be hosted by a form.

So with doing this, you could create separate controls for managing each datagrid.

check out this link on how and what they are used for :-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302342.aspx